# deviceMotionEvent.acceleration properties returning null in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, accelerometer, devicemotion

I'm trying to detect acceleration of a mobile device. I've already tried using Accelerometer and now I'm also trying deviceMotionEvent. Whenever I print the properties  event.acceleration.x, .y, or .z either in html or console, I'd get null. It would be much appreciated if anyone could help me see what I'm doing wrong. When I check sites in browser to see if my device can use accelerometer or deviceMotionEvent, it works there so it's not that my device can't handle it. Here's an iteration pieced together from many google searches I have from body:

```
    <p id="test"> nothing </p>
    <script>
        function motion(event) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "acceleration x:" + event.acceleration.x;

            console.log("Accelerometer: "
                + event.acceleration.x + ", "
                + event.acceleration.y + ", "
                + event.acceleration.z
            );
        }

        if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
            window.addEventListener("devicemotion", motion, false);
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "eventlistner added"
        } else {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "sadness it won't work";
            console.log("DeviceMotionEvent is not supported");
        }
    </script>
```

The text on the doc ends up being "acceleration x:null". Insight is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does the hardware know how to remove gravity? [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceMotionEvent/acceleration): "If the hardware doesn't know how to remove gravity from the acceleration data, this value may not be present in the DeviceMotionEvent. In this situation, you'll need to use DeviceMotionEvent.accelerationIncludingGravity instead."

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley accelerationIncludingGravity also returns null. When I try on [websites that test for the sensors](https://sensor-js.xyz/demo.html) the acceleration data detects both accelerometer and accelerometer including gravity.